# Clustering/Nearest Neighbor

Tags: cluster-analysis, nearest-neighbor

I have thousands to ten-thousands of data points (x,y)coming from 5 to 6 different source. I need to uniquely group them based on certain distance criteria in such a way that the formed group should exactly contain only one input from each source and each of them in the group should be within certain distance d. The groups formed should be the best possible match.

1. Is this a combination of clustering and nearest neighbor?
2. What are the recommendation for the algorithms?
3. Are there any open source available for it?

I see many references saying KD tree implementation and k-clustering etc. I am not sure how can I tailor to this specific need.